# Import pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset class in Cython

Tags: python, pandas, import, cython

I want to import the class `pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset` to fix a bug in a Cython file in the pandas library. Unfortunately, I can't build the `Timedelta` C extension due to an error in my code.

```
    if util.is_string_object(offset):
        from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
        offset = to_offset(offset)
    else:
        from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
        if not isinstance(offset, DateOffset):
            raise ValueError
```

What's wrong with the `pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset` import statement? It works in ipython.

I've created a GitHub Gist with the output of the `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` command: [link](https://gist.github.com/IamGianluca/b916ccb083f1dc663b52)

Comment: You don't need to create an instantiated object with `DateOffset()`, but you need to check if it is an instance of the class itself: `isinstance(offset, DateOffset)`

Comment: @joris that is what I did in the first place. Unfortunately, it doesn't build the C `Timedelta` extension. I've fixed the code snippet in order not to confuse people.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your question precisely what you're seeing in terms of the failure that occurs.

```
if not isinstance(offset, DateOffset) and
if offset is not None:
```

is not valid syntax.

Did you mean

```
if not isinstance(offset, DateOffset) and offset is not None:
```

which is a silly way to write

```
if not isinstance(offset, DateOffset):
```

or something?

Comment: That second if statement was initially commented out. I messed up with the code I pasted here. I've updated the code on the question and added a GitHub Gist with the output of the C extensions built.

Comment: @Gianluca, You get the error message "ImportError: C extension: Timedelta not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first." -- does your local version of pandas need to be built?

Comment: I've tried but I keep receiving the error message I attached in the GitHub Gist in the question.